# Find count and list of duplicate records based on single or multiple column in multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I've two tables below `ActiveSales` and `PastSales`. I want to find duplicate instances from two tables for each item and get count of same ItemID's sold multiple instances for each Item ID from two tables.

requirement: Same ItemID can be sold for 1,2,3 instances irrespective of sold date but  SaleInstances should not be repeated.

```
ActiveSales:
ItemID SaleInstance  SoldDate
10001  1             18-May-2020
10002  1              5-May-2020
10003  2             20-May-2020 



PastSales:

ItemID SaleInstance  SoldDate
13401  2             12-March-2020
10002  1              5-April-2020
10003  1             22-April-2020 
10002  2              15-April-2020
10001  3              2-April-2020 
10003  1             2-Feb-2020 
10002  1              5-March-2020
10001  3             8-April-2020  
10001  1              2-Jan-2020
```

Expected Result:

```
1) Count of Duplicate sale at instance-1 for ItemID - 10001 : 2
   Count of Duplicate sale at instance-2 for ItemID - 10001 : 0
   Count of Duplicate sale at instance-3 for ItemID - 10001 : 2
   Count of Duplicate sale at instance-1 for ItemID - 10002 : 3
   Count of Duplicate sale at instance-2 for ItemID - 10002 : 0
   Count of Duplicate sale at instance-3 for ItemID - 10002 : 0
   Count of Duplicate sale at instance-1 for ItemID - 10003 : 2
   Count of Duplicate sale at instance-2 for ItemID - 10003 : 0
   ..
   ..
   ..

2)   Complete List:

ItemID SaleInstance   SoldDate
10001  1              2-Jan-2020
10001  1             18-May-2020
10001  3              2-April-2020
10001  3             8-April-2020 
10002  1              5-March-2020
10002  1              5-April-2020
10002  1              5-May-2020
10002  2              15-April-2020
10003  1             2-Feb-2020
10003  1             22-April-2020
10003  2             20-May-2020 
13401  2             12-March-2020
```

Comment: So, if the two tables where combined into one table, you would know what to do?

Comment: Why `instance-2 for ItemID - 10002 : 0` and `instance-2 for ItemID - 10003 : 0`? Both have single row in sample input, hence I would expect output 1. Also please use CTE (with clause) rather than plaintext tables to specify your input data. Or prepare dbfiddle. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **HAVING** clause to show you only rows with count > 1

```
select ItemID, SaleInstance 
  from (select * from ActiveSales union all select * from PastSales) t 
group by ItemID, SaleInstance 
  having count(*) > 1
```

Regards
Olafur